# How to find what called a thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

In the Eclipse debugger, I see in the stack trace many calls to Thread.run.  The steps never go beyond that.  How do I find out what method in our code started the thread?  Right-clicking does not provide anything useful. Putting a breakpoint on the run method in Thread.class and  inspecting Target does not, as far as I can tell, say who the caller is.

Comment: You probably want to see stack trace.. if you throw an exception in your thread you’ll get an error message showing it..

Comment: @numbtongue That's the problem.  In order to do that, I'd need to know what called it.  I suppose I could try running java.lang.thread from source code, and then edit it there, but that's a bigger hassle than I was looking for.

Comment: You may be able to find it in the event logs (if on Windows?) or using some kind of 3rd party profiler tool for running processes..

Comment: @numbtongue Linux, fwiw.

Comment: You can’t.  A thread has its own call stack by definition.  If you’re lucky, the thread’s name may be something informative which you can search for in the code.

Comment: @numbtongue, a stack trace of thread A will _not_ show the function that created and started thread A.

Comment: That’s good to know, thanks.. but if the thread is part of a running process may be you could get a stack trace on the process..

Comment: This open source JVM priofiler says it can collect stack traces and inject bytecode https://www.google.com/amp/s/eng.uber.com/jvm-profiler/amp/

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint at the method `java.lang.Thread.start()` to find out where the thread is started.

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the creation of the threads (i.e. you call new Thread() in your code, or provide your own ThreadFactory), you could create your own Thread sub-class, and use that to "inject" the call-stack at the time of thread creation and the call to `start()` into variables that will be on the stack.  For example:

```
public static class KnowledgeableThread extends Thread {

    private static class KnowledgeableRunnable implements Runnable {

        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceAtInit;
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceAtStart;

        private final Runnable actualRunnable;

        KnowledgeableRunnable(Runnable actualRunnable){
            this.actualRunnable = actualRunnable;
            this.stackTraceAtInit = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            actualRunnable.run();
        }
    }

    public KnowledgeableThread(Runnable target, String name) {
        super(new KnowledgeableRunnable(target), name);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {

        try {
            Field[] fields = Thread.class.getDeclaredFields();
            for(Field f : fields){
                if(f.getName().equals("target")){
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    KnowledgeableRunnable knowledgeableRunnable = (KnowledgeableRunnable)f.get(this);
                    knowledgeableRunnable.stackTraceAtStart = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
                }
            }

            super.start();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you stop at a breakpoint "inside" of `actualRunnable.run()` (e.g. the `println` in the code below), and examine the variables at the stack-frame belonging to `KnowledgeableRunnable.run()`, you should have access to the two stack traces.

```
public static void a(Thread kt){
    b(kt);
}
public static void b(Thread kt){
    c(kt);
}
public static void c(Thread kt){
    kt.start();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread kt = new KnowledgeableThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello Foo-Bar");
        }
    }, "my-thread");
    a(kt);
    kt.join();

}
```